# Facebook iOS SDK: requestNewPublishPermissions not initializes permissions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just started using facebook sdk and slightly confused with it documentation. It's well written, but very often does not correspond to current SDK version. So i'm not found what to do with this situation:

I request publish permissions when firstly require them, with the next code:

```
[[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:permissions
                                            defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Permissions request error: %@", error.description);
        }
        completion(error == nil);
    }];
```

I need only one publish permission - 'publish_actions', when i request it sdk redirects me to facebook app and immediately returns back to the my app without asking whether i'm agree to give this permission.
There are no errors in completionHandler, but through debug i found that this permission was saved in the variable **_requestedReauthPermissions**:
[image]

So, finally, permission i requested not granted to me.

How properly request publish permission? What could I miss? May it occur due to setup of facebook app?

Comment: r u enable the 3 permissions in Facebook